# set FlexboxLayout's attribute layout_wrapbefore programmatically

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I have  [`flexbox-layout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) contains `TextView` that have the attribute:

```
app:layout_wrapBefore="true"
```

but I need to set it to `false` programmatically!

any idea on how to do that?

---

the xml, if needed!

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexboxlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:justifyContent="flex_end">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="07:22 PM"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_alignSelf="center"
            app:layout_wrapBefore="true" />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use [setWrapBefore](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/flexbox/src/main/java/com/google/android/flexbox/FlexboxLayout.java#L1738) method as described in its LayoutParams and set those layout params to the TextVuew again.

```
TextView mainTextView = findViewById(R.id.mainText); // or get it as you should
FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams) mainTextView.getLayoutParams();
lp.setWrapBefore(false);
mainTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```