# Make some rows in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager have fewer items, with horizontal shift

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a calendar application, and I need a way to display the dates by month. With RecylcerView, is there a way to make some rows have less items, and have those items shifted over accordingly? For example if the month starts on a Wednesday, the first row would only have 4 items, and the first item in that row would be directly above the 4th item in the rows below it. The items should all have the same size. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to do something like have a complete grid (with no shifts) but somehow get the cells that I don't want to show to be blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `FlexboxLayoutManager` from  https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout might suit your need

When the item is the "First Day of the Week" you would set `wrapBefore` on that item and you would also set `justifyContent` on the layout to be `flex_end`

With this you are manually in control of how many items there are in a row.

Update: while this solution works for the start of the month it just shifts the problem to the end of the month

[image]

I did it in `onBindViewHolder` in the recycler's adapter with the code below, the frame view holder was just the root layout element the recycler's item layout.

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DaysViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Pair<Integer,String> day = dayList.get(position);
        holder.dayNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.ROOT,"%d", day.first));
        holder.dayName.setText(String.format(Locale.ROOT,"%s", day.second));
        if (day.second.equals("Sunday")) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.frame.getLayoutParams();
            FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
            flexboxLp.setWrapBefore(true);
        }
    }
```

If you look at a lot of calendar UI's they pad the start and end of the months with the actual days of previous and next month.

e.g.

[image]

Comment: how do I set wrapBefore on an item? does I need the item need to be inside a flexbox layout, or does any layout work? When i try to set it in a simlar way as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868488/set-flexboxlayouts-attribute-layout-wrapbefore-programmatically, except using FlexBoxLayoutMananger.LayoutParams  with a linear layout, it crashes